# Return value of MPI_Dims_create()

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

Assuming I have `64` processes and I want to create an MPI Cartesian Topology in `3-D`, the default topology returned by `MPI_Dims_create()` is `4x4x4`. Why is it `4x4x4` and why not `8x4x2` or `4x8x2` or `16x2x2` or any other combination that is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_Dims_create` is specifically made as *convenience* function to create a *balanced* topology.

A balanced topology, i.e. ideally cube has a certain optimal properties. Consider you are doing a simulation on a `160x160x160` grid with your processes.

- With `4x4x4` each processor gets `40x40x40` to work on and in case of a simple border exchange has to send `40x40` to each of the 6 neighbors (`9600` in total)
- With `8x4x2` each processor gets `20x40x80`, the border is `2x20x40 + 2x20x80 + 2x40x80 = 11200`
- With `16x2x2` each processor gets `10x80x80`, the border is `4x10x80 + 2x80x80 = 16000`

As you can see, the border size that needs to be exchanged is the smallest for the cube. Generally, a balanced topology is a good default.

You can also set constraints with `MPI_Dims_create` or use `MPI_Cart_create` to create flexible Cartesian topologies.